# Animate control with respecting parents/container

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a control that I move with help of animation from the bottom to the final position. My problem is now that I want to change the behaviour of the animation, so that it respects the outer container (DarkGray).

The orange Ractangle should only be visible on the white background and not on the darkgray Grid!

**Code:**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="DarkGray">
    <Grid Margin="50"
          Background="White">
        <Rectangle x:Name="objectToMove"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                   Fill="Orange"
                   Height="50"
                   Width="50"/>
        <Button Height="20"
                Width="40"
                Margin="20"
                Content="Move" 
                Click="Button_Click"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var target = objectToMove;

    var heightOfControl = target.ActualHeight;
    var trans = new TranslateTransform();
    target.RenderTransform = trans;

    var myAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(heightOfControl, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600));

    trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, myAnimation);
}
```

Current:
[image: Snapshot of the running code snippets]

Desired solution:
[image: Should be like this]

Comment: Try `<Grid Margin="50" Background="White" ClipToBounds="True"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ClipToBounds` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) for this.

```
<Grid Margin="50"
      Background="White"
      ClipToBounds="True">
```